# Heartbeat Analytics Implementation for Video Player

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, adobe-analytics, android-video-player

I have integrated Heartbeat Analytics for video player by going through the sample app in Github - https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/video-heartbeat/releases.

When I track the service call, I find that for the first time, the events are not tracked. But when I click the video for the second time, all the events are tracked and send to the server.

Comment: The android version requires you to explicitly call the various video tracking methods (e.g. `trackPlay()` when the video starts playing). Normally whatever video player framework you use should have callback events you subscribe to, to call the heartbeat methods. You haven't shown any code/details for what your video setup/config is or what you've actually done to call the heartbeat methods.  If I *had* to take a random guess, I would say you either subscribed to a replay event (vs. the actual play event), or...

Comment: ...  perhaps you are starting the video somewhere other than at the beginning and so your video player's framework isn't triggering the (start) play callback (or heartbeat is not starting because position is not at 0 when it's triggered, or `trackVideoLoad` is not otherwise being called based on initial load/play)

Comment: But these are random guesses. You need to provide details for your video setup/config and how you've actually implemented the AA code

Comment: @CrayonViolent ...you were right when I moved trackVideoLoad() to a different place - where I am all set to play the video, all the analytics are tracked for the first time too! The problem was with the correct placing of trackVideoLoad() method. Thanks.